# SQL Server and JSON_VALUE number cast

Tags: json, sql-server

JSON_VALUE returns a string, so is it safe to assume that the internal JSON number->varchar conversion can be cast to a decimal without specifying any culture?

> ```
> {"Salary": 10000.99}
> ```

```
select CAST(JSON_VALUE(jsondata, '$.Salary') AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) from table
```

EDIT: I am worrying that the internal conversion from JSON number to string could be using another decimal separator that the CAST expects

Comment: You want `CAST` not `CASE`, however, if the value can be cast or not completely depends on it's value. A value in the format `#.00` would be able to be cast to a `decimal(12,2)`, yes; provided it wasn't greater/less than ±9999999999.99. If you want to be more explicit, and not have an `nvarchar(MAX)` returned, you could use `OPENJSON` instead, or if you didn't want to take the "chance" that your JSON contains bad data, you could wrap `JSON_VALUE` in `TRY_CAST`/`TRY_CONVERT` instead.

Comment: My mistake, I meant CAST and have changed it now.

Comment: I am worrying that the internal conversion from JSON number to string could be using another decimal separator that the CAST expects

Comment: If you have inconsistent formatting in your JSON, @Stig, the problem is the JSON, not the `CAST`,

Comment: @Larnu the JSON text contains correct formated JSON number (as in the example)

Comment: Then see my first comment, @Stig .

Comment: According to [the JSON specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), a numeric literal cannot have a digit group separator, and must always use `.` as the decimal separator. So I guess it's a question of whether `CAST` ever uses the regional settings for decimal separators.

Comment: For SQL Server 2012 or later, you could use [the `TRY_PARSE` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql) with a known culture instead. But since that involves invoking the CLR, it could affect performance.

Comment: yes the JSON number is not a concern. It is the SQL server conversions that is troubling me. I cannot use TRY_PARSE with a culture if I don't know which culture JSON_VALUE uses.